# tomcat 9 windows redirect stdout stderr in log file and the console

Tags: tomcat9

I use apache-tomcat-9.0.48 in windows environment

and to start it I use startup.bat

**stdout stderr are displayed in the console but not displayed in log file.**

in the logs folder I have 5 files

**localhost.2021-07-4.log
manager.2021-07-4.log
host-manager.2021-07-4.log
catalina.2021-07-4.log
localhost_access_log.2021-07-4.txt**

I want to print all stdout stderr in this file catalina.2021-07-4.log
and in the same time in the console.

I try with this solution:

in **startup.bat**
change `call "%EXECUTABLE%" start %CMD_LINE_ARGS%` with

```
call "%EXECUTABLE%" run %CMD_LINE_ARGS%  >>%CATALINA_HOME%\logs\catalina.%date:~0,4%-%date:~5,2%-%date:~8,2%.out 2>&1
```

and in **catalina.bat** I make :

```
if not "%JPDA%" == "" goto doJpda
if not "%SECURITY_POLICY_FILE%" == "" goto doSecurity
%_EXECJAVA% %CATALINA_LOGGING_CONFIG% %LOGGING_MANAGER% %JAVA_OPTS% %CATALINA_OPTS% %DEBUG_OPTS% -D%ENDORSED_PROP%="%JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS%" -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" -Dcatalina.base="%CATALINA_BASE%" -Dcatalina.home="%CATALINA_HOME%" -Djava.io.tmpdir="%CATALINA_TMPDIR%" %MAINCLASS% %CMD_LINE_ARGS% %ACTION%
%CATALINA_HOME%/logs/catalina.%date:~0,4%-%date:~5,2%-%date :~8,2%.out
goto end
:doSecurity
%_EXECJAVA% %CATALINA_LOGGING_CONFIG% %LOGGING_MANAGER% %JAVA_OPTS% %CATALINA_OPTS% %DEBUG_OPTS% -D%ENDORSED_PROP%="%JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS%" -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=="%SECURITY_POLICY_FILE%" -Dcatalina.base="%CATALINA_BASE%" -Dcatalina.home="%CATALINA_HOME%" -Djava.io.tmpdir="%CATALINA_TMPDIR%" %MAINCLASS% %CMD_LINE_ARGS% %ACTION%
%CATALINA_HOME%/logs/catalina.%date:~0,4%-%date:~5,2%-%date :~8,2%.out
goto end
:doJpda
if not "%SECURITY_POLICY_FILE%" == "" goto doSecurityJpda
%_EXECJAVA% %CATALINA_LOGGING_CONFIG% %LOGGING_MANAGER% %JAVA_OPTS% %JPDA_OPTS% %CATALINA_OPTS% %DEBUG_OPTS% -D%ENDORSED_PROP%="%JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS%" -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" -Dcatalina.base="%CATALINA_BASE%" -Dcatalina.home="%CATALINA_HOME%" -Djava.io.tmpdir="%CATALINA_TMPDIR%" %MAINCLASS% %CMD_LINE_ARGS% %ACTION%
%CATALINA_HOME%/logs/catalina.%date:~0,4%-%date:~5,2%-%date :~8,2%.out
goto end
:doSecurityJpda
%_EXECJAVA% %CATALINA_LOGGING_CONFIG% %LOGGING_MANAGER% %JAVA_OPTS% %JPDA_OPTS% %CATALINA_OPTS% %DEBUG_OPTS% -D%ENDORSED_PROP%="%JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS%" -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=="%SECURITY_POLICY_FILE%" -Dcatalina.base="%CATALINA_BASE%" -Dcatalina.home="%CATALINA_HOME%" -Djava.io.tmpdir="%CATALINA_TMPDIR%" %MAINCLASS% %CMD_LINE_ARGS% %ACTION%
%CATALINA_HOME%/logs/catalina.%date:~0,4%-%date:~5,2%-%date :~8,2%.out
goto end
```

and this is the configuaration in **logging.properties**

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, 2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, 3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################

1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = catalina.
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.maxDays = 90
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.encoding = UTF-8

2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = localhost.
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.maxDays = 90
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.encoding = UTF-8

3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = manager.
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.maxDays = 90
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.encoding = UTF-8

4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = host-manager.
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.maxDays = 90
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.encoding = UTF-8

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = org.apache.juli.OneLineFormatter
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.encoding = UTF-8


############################################################
# Facility specific properties.
# Provides extra control for each logger.
############################################################

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].handlers = 3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].handlers = 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler

# For example, set the org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase logger to log
# each component that extends LifecycleBase changing state:
#org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.level = FINE

# To see debug messages in TldLocationsCache, uncomment the following line:
#org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache.level = FINE

# To see debug messages for HTTP/2 handling, uncomment the following line:
#org.apache.coyote.http2.level = FINE

# To see debug messages for WebSocket handling, uncomment the following line:
#org.apache.tomcat.websocket.level = FINE
```

with this solution the error are only displayed in this kind of file **catalina.Sun**

and not displayed in the console

**updated :**

I have a web application using jhipster angular  which is deplyed in
**C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.48\webapps**

now I have removed my configuration in startap.bat and catalina.bat

I make `call "%EXECUTABLE%" start %CMD_LINE_ARGS%` in startap.bat

I make in context.xml this configuration

```
<Context>

    <!-- Default set of monitored resources. If one of these changes, the    -->
    <!-- web application will be reloaded.                                   -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/tomcat-web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>
<Context swallowOutput="true" />
    <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
    <!--
    <Manager pathname="" />
    -->
</Context>
```

but I still have the application error in the console and not in log file

Answer (score 0):

Remark: printing to `System.out`/`System.err` is not a proper way of logging. If you want to log something in **your own application**, use a proper logging system.

If you want to redirect stdout/stderr to Tomcat's own logging system use the `swallowOutput` attribute of your context's configuration (cf. [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Common_Attributes)). If you have an application in `webapps/app` or `webapps/app.war` this sums up (assuming that you didn't change your engine and host names) to creating a file `conf/Catalina/localhost/app.xml` with content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context swallowOutput="true" />
```

Comment: thank you for your response, I have updated my question, but using <Context swallowOutput="true" />  the errors  are not found in log file,    also the problem that in linux environment all application errors are found in catalina.out.  but in windows environment  I didn't find catalina.out

Comment: You added another `<Context>` element to `conf/context.xml`, instead of modifying the existing one. Change the external `<Context>` to `<Context swallowOutput="true">`. BTW: reading the logs helps with configuration errors. Inserting a `<Context>` element inside another `<Context>` element causes a warning _"No rules found matching [Context/Context]"_ to be printed.